# How to use Tablesorter with column selector widget - error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm attempting to use [Mottie's Tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) with the [Column Selector widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) using the example Bootstrap popover code provided in the documentation.  However, I'm getting a Javascript exception thrown inside the `columnSelector` widget library.  What am I doing wrong?  Or is there perhaps an actual bug in one of the Tablesorter libraries in use?

Here is a link to a JS Fiddle which demonstrates the error:
https://jsfiddle.net/qmnev5wr/5/

You'll have to view the JS console in e.g. a browser's dev tools to see the error message live, but here's what I get:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: o is undefined attachTo@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.2/js/widgets/widget-columnSelector.min.js:3:8917
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/noh4293y/) which fixed the following issues:

- Added missing popper.js (Bootstrap requires it for popups)
- Loaded bootstrap.js *after* popper.js
- Added bootstrap.css
- Added CSS copied from the tablesorter example page
- Removed `$("#claim-table").tablesorter(...)` because it was initializing the table without the widgets - it's already being initialized inside the document ready function

Comment: I greatly appreciate the response.  Did I miss reading about `popper.js` somewhere in the documentation?